# How to use Yeoman with Angular 5 frame work

Tags: angular

I am just baffled about how to use yeoman with angular 5.Both angular and yeoman has the file structues. which one i used to go ahead and start developing. I am new to yeoman.so, please help to get rid of it.

Comment: you can simply use `angular-cli` to achieve the same

Comment: I already installed angular cli

Comment: where am i write my html and js files ?

Comment: angular CLI work with angular 2+, so you don't have JS file but TS, with command line you can create your component, service, directive...

For example :

ng generate component MyComponentName

this command will create all necessary file : (html, css, module.ts, component.ts) in a folder called with your component name

Comment: then what is the purpose of  `yeoman`

Comment: But I want to use `yeoman` to generate component, service, directives